# XML xpath - passing a value if the element is not found

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xpath

I am currently trying to parse an XML file, the code below works fine except for one issue. In the case of the full_names list I create, this is the only tag that does not always appear in each sub tree i.e. `user_names`, `profiles`, & `authentication` types all return say 30 items, while `full_name` returns 27.

Therefore when I am trying to create the `dataframe`, I get an error because the lists are of different lengths.

```
xmltree = ET.parse(xml)
namespaces = {'ns5':'urn:swift:saa:xsd:operator',
              'profile':'urn:swift:saa:xsd:operatorprofile'
             }

user_names = xmltree.xpath('//ns5:Identifier/ns5:Name/text()', namespaces=namespaces)
full_names = xmltree.xpath('//ns5:Description/text()', namespaces=namespaces)
profiles = xmltree.xpath('//profile:Name/text()', namespaces=namespaces)
authentication_types = xmltree.xpath('//ns5:AuthenticationType/text()', namespaces=namespaces)

xml = pd.DataFrame({'User_Name': user_names, 'Full_Name': full_names,
                    'Profile': profiles, 'Authentication_Type': authentication_types})
```

Is there a way of doing this so that the `dataframe` can be created with null values (or blanks) in the full names column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about this last night and realised that I would need to identify the parent tag and loop through it looking for child tags. Changed my approach and it is now working the way I want it.

For anyone who faces the problem, here is the fix I used.

```
root = xmltree.getroot()

user_names = []
full_names = []
profiles = []
authentication_types = []

for i in root.findall('.//{urn:swift:saa:xsd:impex:operator}Operator'):
    usernames = i.find('.//{urn:swift:saa:xsd:operator}Name')
    usernames2 = "" if usernames is None else usernames.text
    user_names.append(usernames2)

    fullnames = i.find('{urn:swift:saa:xsd:operator}Description')
    fullnames2 = "" if fullnames is None else fullnames.text
    full_names.append(fullnames2)

    user_profiles = i.find('.//{urn:swift:saa:xsd:operatorprofile}Name')
    user_profiles2 = "" if user_profiles is None else user_profiles.text
    profiles.append(user_profiles2)

    authenications = i.find('{urn:swift:saa:xsd:operator}AuthenticationType')
    authenications2 = "" if authenications is None else authenications.text
    authentication_types.append(authenications2)

    xml = pd.DataFrame({'User_Name': user_names,
                        'Full_Name': full_names,
                        'Profile': profiles,
                        'Authentication_Type': authentication_types})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, didnt test on you code cause is not full to reproduce

```
full_names = xmltree.xpath('//ns5:Description/text()', namespaces=namespaces) if xmltree.xpath('//ns5:Description/text()', namespaces=namespaces) else ""
```

or same code in multiple lines

```
full_names = xmltree.xpath('//ns5:Description/text()', namespaces=namespaces)
if not full_name:
    full_names = ""
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, but unfortunately this doesn't work as the "if xmltree.xpath('//ns5:Description/text()', namespaces=namespaces)" would return as True because there would be some elements in the list. Also, I suppose the other issue is that the xpath will just look for entries that match, it wouldn't understand that in some cases there are elements missing, so maybe I need to figure out how to loop over a parent tag and search within that tag.